# Flutter Error : VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings

Tags: android, flutter

added flutter to my existing project as a module and getting this crash.
by following this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps).

```
2019-06-24 11:08:24.366 30834-30834/com.alarmnet.tc2 E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_data.cc(19)] VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings.
2019-06-24 11:08:24.366 30834-30834/com.alarmnet.tc2 E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(241)] Could not setup VM data to bootstrap the VM from.
2019-06-24 11:08:24.366 30834-30834/com.alarmnet.tc2 E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(89)] Could not create Dart VM instance.
2019-06-24 11:08:24.366 30834-30834/com.alarmnet.tc2 A/flutter: [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(218)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
2019-06-24 11:08:24.368 30834-30834/com.alarmnet.tc2 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 30834 (om.alarmnet.tc2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a fix for it :

If you trying to add a flutter to your existing project as per this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps)

Open your Flutter SDK : FlutterSdk/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle

- open flutter.gradle in any of the editors and do the following changes

from :

```
   // We know that the flutter app is a subproject in another Android app when these tasks exist.
Task packageAssets = project.tasks.findByPath(":flutter:package${variant.name.capitalize()}Assets")
Task cleanPackageAssets = project.tasks.findByPath(":flutter:cleanPackage${variant.name.capitalize()}Assets")
Task copyFlutterAssetsTask = project.tasks.create(name: "copyFlutterAssets${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Copy) {
dependsOn flutterTasks
if (packageAssets && cleanPackageAssets) {
dependsOn packageAssets
dependsOn cleanPackageAssets
into packageAssets.outputDir
} else {
dependsOn variant.mergeAssets
dependsOn "clean${variant.mergeAssets.name.capitalize()}"
into variant.mergeAssets.outputDir
}
flutterTasks.each { flutterTask ->
with flutterTask.assets
// Include the snapshots in the assets directory.
if (flutterBuildMode != 'release' || targetPlatformValue != 'android-arm-all') {
with flutterTask.snapshots
}
}
}
  if (packageAssets) {
      String mainModuleName = "app"
     try {
               String tmpModuleName = project.rootProject.ext.mainModuleName
               if (tmpModuleName != null && !tmpModuleName.empty) {
            mainModuleName = tmpModuleName
     }
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
 Only include configurations that exist in parent project.
 Task mergeAssets = project.tasks.findByPath(":${mainModuleName}:merge${variant.name.capitalize()}Assets")
      if (mergeAssets) {
        mergeAssets.dependsOn(copyFlutterAssetsTask)
  }
} else {
  def processResources = variant.outputs.first().processResources
  processResources.dependsOn(copyFlutterAssetsTask)
 }
```

To :

```
    // We know that the flutter app is a subproject in another Android app when these tasks exist.
Task packageAssets = project.tasks.findByPath(":flutter:package${variant.name.capitalize()}Assets")
Task cleanPackageAssets = project.tasks.findByPath(":flutter:cleanPackage${variant.name.capitalize()}Assets")
Task copyFlutterAssetsTask = project.tasks.create(name: "copyFlutterAssets${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Copy) {
dependsOn flutterTasks
if (packageAssets && cleanPackageAssets) {
dependsOn packageAssets
dependsOn cleanPackageAssets
into packageAssets.outputDir
} else {
dependsOn variant.mergeAssets
dependsOn "clean${variant.mergeAssets.name.capitalize()}"
into variant.mergeAssets.outputDir
}
flutterTasks.each { flutterTask ->
with flutterTask.assets
// Include the snapshots in the assets directory.
if (flutterBuildMode != 'release' || targetPlatformValue != 'android-arm-all') {
with flutterTask.snapshots
}
}
}
//  if (packageAssets) {
//      String mainModuleName = "app"
//      try {
//               String tmpModuleName = project.rootProject.ext.mainModuleName
//               if (tmpModuleName != null && !tmpModuleName.empty) {
//             mainModuleName = tmpModuleName
//     }
//   } catch (Exception e) {
//   }
// Only include configurations that exist in parent project.
// Task mergeAssets = project.tasks.findByPath(":${mainModuleName}:merge${variant.name.capitalize()}Assets")
//      if (mergeAssets) {
//        mergeAssets.dependsOn(copyFlutterAssetsTask)
//  }
//} else {
//  def processResources = variant.outputs.first().processResources
//  processResources.dependsOn(copyFlutterAssetsTask)
// }
def processResources = variant.outputs.first().processResources
processResources.dependsOn(copyFlutterAssetsTask)
```

save and follow this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps)

Comment: Hi, the content of gradle file has changed in the updated version but the issue is still there, I'm using Flutter version 2.10.3, can you please check and help

Answer (score 1):

if you are added flutter in the existing app go to flutter module --> .android --> build.gradle. classpath must be same as of Android

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
```